# Dynamically concatenating array in Vue from ajax request not working

Tags: javascript, arrays, vue.js

I have a fairly simple Vue instance that retrieves objects from a REST endpoint and displays them on a page. Pretty much everything works correctly (filtering, for example) except when I go to add new objects to the set of results by asking for a new "page" of results from the service. The difference between this operation and my other operations is that I'm attempting to add new results from the service to the existing set of results. Because the service only returns the requested "page" of results, I can't replace the array entirely, instead I must add to the existing set of results in my Vue instance. Here's the code in question:

```
// these come from an external server-side process rendered in a separate place so are defined outside of the Vue context
let searchTags = ["tag1", "tag2", "etc"];
let productsBaseSearchTag = "a/b/c";

Vue.mixin({
    methods: {
        doSearchStuff: function(response, data) {
            this.searchResponse = response;
            this.resultCount = response.total; // this doesn't seem to be working consistently either so I'm doing it with jQuery
            jQuery(".search-page-sort-results .num").text(this.resultCount);
            if(this.currentPage > 1) {
                this.searchResults = this.searchResults.concat(data.hits);
            } else {
                this.searchResults = data.hits;
            }
            this.facetCount = data.facets.length;
        }
    }
});

new Vue({
    el: '#v-search-page-results',
    data: {
        searchResponse: {},
        searchResults: [],
        facetHeaders: searchTags,
        returnedFacetHeaders: undefined,
        currentPage: 1,
        hitsPerPage: 12,
        searchTerm: "",
        statusMessage: "",
        sortProperty: "",
        displayedFilters: {},
        predicateList: [],
        facetCount: 0,
        resultCount: 0,
        showLoading: true
    },
    created: function() {
        this.predicateList = searchTags;
        this.getSearchResults(false);
    },
    computed: {
        pdpPaths: function() {
            return this.searchResults.map(function(item) {
                let catalogPath = item.path;
                return decodeURIComponent(pdpPath) + catalogPath.replace(decodeURIComponent(catalogRoot), "").replace(/\//g, ".");
            });
        },
        summaries: function() {
            return this.searchResults.map(function(item) {
                let summary = item.properties.summary;
                if (summary.length >= 120) {
                    summary = summary.substring(0, 120);
                    summary = summary.substring(0, summary.lastIndexOf(" ")) + "...";
                }
                return summary;
            });
        },
        assetAbsoluteURLs: function() {
            return this.searchResults.map(function(item) {
                let escapedUrl = item.path.replace(/\s/g, "%20");
                return location.origin + escapedUrl;
            });
        },
        canClearFilters: function() {
            return this.predicateList !== searchTags;
        },
        moreResults: function() {
            if(this.searchResponse) {
                let resultCount = this.resultCount;
                let totalLoadedResults = this.hitsPerPage * this.currentPage;
                if(totalLoadedResults < resultCount) {
                    return true;
                }
            }
            return false;
        }
    },
    methods: {
        loadMoreResults: function() {
            this.currentPage += 1;
            this.getSearchResults();
        },
        clearSearchTerm: function() {
            this.searchTerm = "";
            this.submitSearchTerm();
        },
        getSearchFilters: function() {
            if(this.predicateList.length > 0) {
                return this.predicateList;
            } else {
                this.predicateList = searchTags;
                return this.predicateList;
            }
        },
        getSearchResults: function(xhrAsync=true) {
            let query = this.buildQuery();

            var jqXhr = $.ajax({
                url: query,
                async: xhrAsync, // search breaks if we don't set this to false on the initial page load search
                context: this
            });

            if(!this.returnedFacetHeaders) {
                jqXhr.done(function(response) {
                    let data = response;
                    this.doSearchStuff(response, data);

                    this.returnedFacetHeaders = data.facetHeaders;

                    if(queryParams.q) {
                        this.searchTerm = decodeURIComponent(queryParams.q);
                    }
                    if(queryParams.tags) {
                        this.predicateList = queryParams.tags;
                    }
                }).done(function () {
                    this.getSearchResults();
                });
            } else {
                jqXhr.done(function(response) {
                    let data = response;
                    this.doSearchStuff(response, data);
                });
            }
        },
        submitSearchTerm: function() {
            this.resetSearch();
        },
        resetSearch: function() {
            this.currentPage = 1;
            this.getSearchResults();
        },
        buildQuery: function() {
            let offset = (this.currentPage - 1) * this.hitsPerPage;

            query = "..."; // not relevant

            return query;
        }
    }
});
```

There's a lot more going on in the code than this but this is the relevant portion relating to the array. It isn't updated outside of this block. And here's the corresponding markup with the v-for that iterates over the array:

```
<div id="v-search-page-results" class="search-page-container _clearfix">
    <div class="search-page-wrapper">
        <div class="search-page-facets-wrapper">
            <div class="search-page-sort-results">
                <span v-cloak class="num">{{ resultCount }}</span> results
            </div>

        </div>

        <div class="search-page-container">

            <!-- facet stuff here -->

            <div class="search-page-results-container">
                <div class="search-page-results-wrapper">

                    <div v-for="(result, index) in searchResults" class="search-page-results-item" v-bind:key="result.id">
                        <div class="search-page-image-container">
                            <img v-cloak :alt="result.title" :src="result.properties.thumbnailPath" class="search-page-image">
                        </div>
                        <div class="search-page-results-content">
                            <a v-cloak :href="pdpPaths[index] + '.html'" class="title" title="">{{ result.properties.productTitle }}</a>
                            <div v-cloak class="description" v-html="summaries[index]"></div>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                </div>

                <div class="search-button-top-nav">
                    <div v-show="moreResults" class="button-wrapper load-more-container load-more-wrapper">
                        <div class="button-wrapper-2">
                            <div class="button-container">
                                <a @click="loadMoreResults" class="btn -primary load-more">Load More</a>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

And, finally, this is an example of the data we are attempting to iterate over:

```
"hits": [
    {
      "id": 1,
      "title": "product1",
      "path": "/path/to/product1",
      "properties": {
        "thumbnailPath": "/products/images/product1.jpg",
        "productTitle": "Product 1",
        "summary": "<p>This is product 1.</p>\r\n"
      }
    },
    {
      "id": 2,
      "title": "product2",
      "path": "/path/to/product2",
      "properties": {
        "thumbnailPath": "/products/images/product2.jpg",
        "productTitle": "Product 2",
        "summary": "<p>This is product 2.</p>\r\n"
      }
    }
]
```

I've tried using Vue.set, I've tried iterating over the response objects and pushing to the array one object at a time, I've tried using the spread operator, etc. In the code the array is being successfully added to, but Vue won't show the new results. If I overwrite an existing object in the current array with a new object, it displays correctly, so it isn't that the DOM isn't being updated at all, it's just being updated to only show the first X number of results, never more than that. It seems like it should work, but it just isn't.

Comment: Just to confirm, you've got two separate properties called `searchResponse` and `searchResults`? Is `searchResults` being defined by your `data` function?

Comment: Correct, both are defined on the Vue instance. It's redundant, I know, since the searchResponse object contains the results I am interested in (and assign to searchResults) but that shouldn't cause a reactivity issue, should it?

Comment: The symptoms you've described would make perfect sense if `searchResults` were not defined in the `data` function. Can you double check it's there and is spelt correctly?

Comment: Ok, but just to clarify this is a Vue instance, not a Vue component, so my properties are defined in the data object, not the data function, and I have double-checked and searchResults is indeed defined on the instance data object. Something just occurred to me, though. Would having an instance method named "getSearchResults" in addition to an instance property being called "searchResults" potentially cause a problem?

Comment: So long as the names aren't the same it won't be a problem. I don't see any obvious cause in the code you've provided. If you'd like further help debugging this I think you're going to have to provide a complete example that we can run ourselves. You may well find the problem yourself while trying to create a suitable, minimal test case.

Comment: Yep, I think you're right. It'll take a bit to clean it all up for that but I will update asap. Thanks.

Comment: @skirtle I have updated the example to show a lot more code and markup.

Comment: If you would like further help please provide a complete, minimal test case. https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example Debugging needs something we can run.

Answer (score 1):

You should not use jQuery mixed with Vue - you'll end up losing reactivity by manipulating the DOM directly, or experience some other ill effects.

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    searchResults: [],
  },
  methods: {
    async getNewPost(next) {
      this.searchResults.push(await this.getSearchResult(next))
    },
    getSearchResult(next) {
      return fetch(`https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/${next}`)
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(json => {
          return json
        })
    }
  },
  async mounted() {
    this.searchResults = [await this.getSearchResult(this.searchResults.length + 1)]

  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <button @click="getNewPost(searchResults.length + 1)">Get new post</button>
  <div v-for="(result, index) in searchResults" class="search-page-results-item" v-bind:key="result.id">
    <div class="search-page-results-content">
      <h3>{{index + 1}}. {{result.title}}</h3>
      <div v-cloak class="description">{{result.body}}</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

The snippet above gets data from a mockup JSON API, and on the push of the button gets the next item.

You can see that in the `getNewPost()` method I do not push items **directly** in the `searchResults` data property, but create a temporary variable and then change the **whole array**.

Comment: I was using Axios originally but it was causing some compatibility issues in the browsers I have to support. I am aware of no documented reactivity issues with using jQuery.ajax. Can you point me to anything that mentions this? Nevertheless I will try using native JS fetch and see if that fixes the issue. Thanks.

Comment: @adammtlx Using `jQuery.ajax` will not cause reactivity issues.

Comment: `fetch` already returns a promise, there's no need to wrap it in another. The line `this.searchResults = await r` seems odd as `r` is an array so `await` won't do anything. Also, `this.searchResults` is already equal to `r`, so that whole line can be removed.

Comment: @adammtlx `jQuery.ajax` itself won't cause reactivity issues. I was pointing out that mixing **jQuery** with **Vue** may cause problems - like directly manipulating the DOM with jQuery that Vue does not "track".

Comment: @muka.gergely My main issue with this approach is that I must support IE11, so even if it solves my issue I'm still left with a problem. :(

Comment: Oh, I see... now that’s a problem.